# Django Rest DRF : accessing a foreign key reference from reverse relation

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, reverse

Let's say I have two models.

> Model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    # other fields

class ItemRelation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='relations_item')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='relations_user')
    has_viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_loved = models.BooleanFields(default=False)
```

Now, what I want to do is to get the profile of one user which would contain the items associated with that user having has_loved=True and has_viewed=True.

In my views.py file I had something like this.

```
class UserProfile(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        id = self.request.query_params.get('id')
        user = User.objects.filter(id=id).prefetch_related(Prefetch(
            'relations_user', queryset=ItemRelation.objects.select_related('item').filter(has_viewed=True),
             to_attr='item_viewed'
    ))
```

I was certain that I was wrong and I also got a serializer error, since I was trying to serialize an ItemRelation object using a serializer which used the Item as its model.

> EDIT

**serializers.py**

```
class ItemSerializer(seralizer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relations_user = ItemSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'relations_user']
```

Comment: where are you serializers? show the ```serializers.py```. And you don't declare any ```serializer_class``` in your view.

Comment: well not using rest_framework.generics here so no serializer_class, and also I'm certain that my problem lies with how I'm querying the items using Prefetch.

Comment: you talk about a serializer error, why do you talk about it if there's no problem with it?

Comment: well, i think I might have misphrased a bit, but the reason of my erroris written just above the EDIT block

Comment: btw, I think you're thinking about serializer. errors which as far as I know occurs on writable serializers during post requests. This is a get request so what I got was a Serialozer Error when I issued a proper get request to the api emdpoint. The main point is not the serializer error here, but how to access the forward relation FK object through an already existing reverse relation.

Comment: well can you print the error you have when doing your request please?

Comment: what you want is unclear: the id you got in your view, it's an user id? And you want then to have the items or another user who has the same liked and viewed item?

Answer (score 0):

First off: It seems you are trying to model some sort of many-to-many relationship in your data and it would be better using the appropriate Django [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).

That being said, a possible solution to your problem may look like this, implementing it via a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

**views.py**

```
class UserProfile(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pk = self.request.query_params.get('id')

        # consider using get_object_or_404 here or implement some
        # other sort of error handling for a failed lookup
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from .models import Item


class ItemSerializer(seralizer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'items']

    def get_items(self, obj):
        # obj is the User instance you call the serializer with
        items = Item.objects.filter(
                    relations_item__user=obj,
                    relations_item__has_viewed=True,
                    relations_item__has_loved=True,
                )

        # serialize the items with your ItemSerializer defined above
        serializer = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)

        return serializer.data
```

Basically, you use a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) which kicks off an additional query filtering for Items which are related to the User and have the properties `has_viewed==True` and `has_loved==True`.

Note that this is not optimal because:

- You are executing an additional query in your serializer.
- You are manually modelling a many-to-many-relation without using the appropriate Django Field (see above).
- In this case, we are manually using a `SerializerMethodField` instead of letting DRF take care of displaying relations.

Comment: this is what I am doing currently, and well this makes a lot of  hits to the database , Thanks for the feedback though